# Laravel 9 midleware not working on route controller group

Tags: laravel, controller, middleware

I am trying to create a new middleware, that should filter all routes bellonging to a specific controller, specifically when a specific controller hit, the middleware should check if the user is logged in.
This is what I have so far in terms of setup, but the user is not redirected to the login page when not authenticated. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, just can't figgure it out what. Thanks.

**Middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class UserIsAuthenticated extends Middleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Auth::guard('host')->check()){
            return redirect('/?login=true');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Kernel**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        // some other routes middleware
        'userauthenticated' => App\Http\Middleware\UserIsAuthenticated::class
    ];
}
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::controller(HostController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('host', 'dashboard');
    Route::get('host/properties', 'properties');
})->middleware('userauthenticated');
```

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: Why would you not just use the default auth middleware? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#specifying-a-guard

Comment: `php artisan route:list` and see what middleware is assigned to those route